# I have a simple compositing setup with four objects.... They render transparent but I would like them all to render out solid

Tags: compositing-nodes

in camera view there are four objects each one is behind the other... slightly obstructing the one in front of it so I could get an idea of how the alpha over node works ...I basically need just a compositing setup that will render out these four objects but each one being completely opaque... Any help is appreciated... Here is my blend file ... The picture on the top with all opaque objects is how I would like my render to look... The picture on the bottom is how it looks now

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bJlNV5duZHz_8C_d8DFmXzUNd5s6A8fq/view?usp=sharing
[image: how I would like it to look]
[[image: screenshot of render][1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your objects to be opaque then **you should not** mix them with a Fac of `0.5` like you did here :

[image]

A Mix Factor of 0.5 means that the image on top would be 50% opaque and the remaining 50% will be for the image on the bottom. The Alpha Over node puts an image on top of another using the alpha of the top image to blend the two, the Fac in this  case is just used as a multiplier for the blending. In you case, your images all have their own alpha channel so if you use an Alpha Over node, you just set the Fac to `1` for all of them and you will obtain the desired result :

[image]

Comment: +1 Oops, you were quicker... I was still writing my answer. But that's it exactly.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ^^'

Comment: That happens to me a lot. Sometimes a new answer just pop up just when I finished typing the answer and it looks exactly like mine.

Comment: Yep, same here... well, of course they look exactly like yours, because they are the correct answers ;)

Comment: OK thank you so much you're so nice to do that for me!!...getting ready to try out the Enrich add on for Blender for compositing today....and it's so nice to have this set up so now I could just render my scenes...with a reusable node setup...because I figured out after masking stuff for hours  in After Effects to do color correction last night ....that maybe the best way is to just render it out perfect at the start using a good compositing set up and Enrich add on for Blender... Because in 3-D modeling software to mask out an object and color correct it...is as simple as unjoining it'yay

Comment: Since it requires a lot of videos to truly grow your YouTube channel nowadays, unless you get lucky...it's so awesome to be able to render a video out of Blender and instantly upload it to YouTube!!... That saves a lot of mouse clicks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: .... stay up my friend